# Solving $x^{-x^{1-x}}=\sqrt[\sqrt2]{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

> $$\large x^{-x^{1-x}}=\large\sqrt[\sqrt2]{2}$$ $$x=?$$

Here is what I've tried:

Since RHS is $2^{\frac1{\sqrt2}}$, base of LHS should be in the form $2^a$. I checked $x=\frac12$  is an answer but not sure if there are other answers. Using $x=2^a$ left side will be equal to,

$$\large(2^a)^{\large-(2^a)^{\large(1-2^a)}}=\large(2^a)^{\large-2^{\large(a-a2^a)}}=\large2^{\large-a\times2^{\large(a-a2^a)}}$$

Hence we have $$a.2^{a(1-2^a)}={\frac{1}2}$$But don't know how to continue further.

Comment: (i) $x=\frac14$ is another root. (ii) You should have obtained $a2^{a(1-2^a)}=\color{red}{-2^{-1/2}}$.

Comment: Plotting $x^{-x^{1-x}}$ shows that there are exactly two roots. They cannot be found in closed-form depending from right-hand side expression. The possible way to solve is to express right-hand side in form corresponding to left-hand side, like $\sqrt[\sqrt{2}]{2}=(1/2)^{-(1/2)^{1-1/2}}=(1/4)^{-(1/4)^{1-1/4}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=x^{-x}$. Then
$$x^{-x^{1-x}}=y^y=\sqrt[\sqrt{2}]{2}=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}>1$$
Now the equation
$$z^z=w$$
has one [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Square_super-root) if $w\geq 1$, and two if $e^{-1/e}<w<1$. Hence,
$$y=\sqrt{2}$$
Rewriting in terms of $x$,
$$x^x=(1/2)^{1/2}<1$$
It follows that $x=1/2$ is one solution, and it is easy to check that $x=1/4$ must be the second solution.

Comment: It is amazing that, using the fact that the maximum of  $x^{-x^{1-x}}$ being at $x=\frac 1e$, using Taylor around this point (to $O(x^3)$, the solutions are $x_1=0.245095$ and $x_2=0.490664$. I suppose that is is probably because $e^{e^{\frac{1}{e}-1}}=1.70142$ is quite close to the rhs ($1.63253$)